# retain the custom header of the original email when we forward the email using logic apps

Tags: azure, azure-functions, sendgrid, azure-logic-apps

when ever a new email arrives to the mailbox, i need to forward the email with the custom header of the original email message. right now we can forward the email message but the custom header of the forwarded email is different from the original message. is there an option to forward or re-direct the email to others using the same custom headers of the original email message.

Iam working on the requirement to maintain the consistency of the below 6 headers, while forwarding the email. (the forwarded email should maintain the same custom headers as original email)

‘Message-Id’ in header

‘In-Reply-To’ field in header

‘References’ in header

‘subject’ because we calculate a ThreadHash to search for an outbound email for the same contact that has the same ThreadHash

‘From’

‘To’

kinldy suggest any alternative steps to achieve this result.

Comment: The outlook and sendgrid connector in logic app don't support custom header. So you could use logic app with Azure function, in the function forward email.

Comment: @GeorgeChen thanks for the response. we cannot retain the Email headers when we forward the message, but however we can copy the value of the email headers to a new custom headers. I figured it out using the microsoft graph api to create a new custom header and implemented in the solution.